# Convergence in probability of product and division of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

How can I prove the following:

Let $X_i$ and $Y_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$, $X$ and $Y$ be random variables defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ and assume that $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ and $Y_n$ to $Y$ (also in probability). Then:

If $Y_n \ne 0$ and $Y \ne 0$ almost surely, then $X_n/Y_n$ converges in probability to $X/Y$.

I tried the following:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. We need to show that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(|X_n/Y_n - X/Y| > \epsilon) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.
\end{align*}
Define $Z_n := 1/Y_n$ and $Z := 1/Y$. $Z_n$ and $Z$ are well defined, since $Y_n, Y \ne 0$ a.s. It is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(|Z_n-Z| > \epsilon) &= \mathbb P(|1/Y_n - 1/Y| > \epsilon) \\
&= \mathbb P(|Y-Y_n|/|Y_nY| > \epsilon) \\
&= \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > \epsilon |Y_n||Y|) \\
&\le \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > \epsilon (|Y|-|Y_n-Y|)|Y|) \\
&= \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > \epsilon (|Y|-|Y_n-Y|)|Y|, |Y_n-Y| \le |Y|/2) \\
&\quad + \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > \epsilon (|Y|-|Y_n-Y|)|Y|, |Y_n-Y| > |Y|/2) \\
&\le \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > \epsilon Y^2/2) + \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > |Y|/2).
\end{align*} 
Now for any $A > 0$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > \epsilon Y^2/2) 
&= \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > \epsilon Y^2/2, |Y| \ge 1/A) + \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > \epsilon Y^2/2, |Y| < 1/A) \\
&\le \mathbb P\left(|Y_n-Y| > \frac{\epsilon}{2A^2}\right) + \mathbb P(|Y| < 1/A)
\xrightarrow{n \to \infty}  \mathbb P(|Y| < 1/A)
\end{align*}
and similarly
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > |Y|/2) &= \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > |Y|/2, |Y| \ge 1/A) + \mathbb P(|Y_n-Y| > |Y|/2, |Y| < 1/A) \\
&\le \mathbb P\left(|Y_n-Y| > \frac{1}{2A}\right)  + \mathbb P(|Y| < 1/A)
\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \mathbb P(|Y| < 1/A).
\end{align*}
Since we can choose $A$ arbitrarily large, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(|Z_n-Z| > \epsilon) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.
\end{align*}
The result follows since we know that $X_nZ_n$ converges to $XZ$ in probability.

Edit: Is it complete now? Is there maybe a shorter proof? Maybe my estimations are too long or there is shorter way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimates look correct, but it seems not clear how to get the wanted convergence (we indeed have the probability that $|Y_n-Y|$ is greater than a positive number, but this one is random).

However, the problem can be solved in this way: fix $\delta$ a small number and $A$ such that $\mathbb P\{|Y|\leqslant A\}\lt \delta$. Then we decompose the probabilities obtained in the last estimate of the OP computations over the set $\{|Y|\leqslant A^{-1}\}$ and its complement.

For example, here is the proof that $\mathbb P\{|Y_n-Y|\geqslant \varepsilon |Y|^2\}\to 0$. We have $$\{|Y_n-Y|\geqslant \varepsilon |Y|^2\}= (\{|Y_n-Y|\geqslant \varepsilon |Y|^2\}\cap \{Y\geqslant A\})\cup (\{|Y_n-Y|\geqslant \varepsilon |Y|^2\}\cap \{Y\lt A\})\\
\subset  \{|Y_n-Y|\geqslant \varepsilon A^2\}\cup\{Y\lt A\}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that. What does the abbreviation OP mean?

Comment: OP means "Opening Post". Don't hesitate if you need more details.

Comment: I have troubles with the decomposition of the last estimate. Could you please provide a few more details? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited. Is it clearer.

Comment: Why is that inclusion true? I don't see why $\{|Y_n-Y| \ge \epsilon |Y|^2\} \cap \{Y \le A\} \subseteq \{|Y_n-Y| \ge \epsilon A^2\}$.

Comment: If $\omega$ is in the LHS, then $|Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)|\geqslant \varepsilon |Y|^2\geqslant \varepsilon A^2$.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the stupid question, but we assume that $Y \le A$, so $|Y|^2 = Y^2 \le A^2$. But you do exactly the opposite. Why is that possible?

Comment: It's not a stupid question, it was a silly mistake from me. I've edited (and also the second paragraph, hence there is an other condition on $A$).

Comment: Ah, thank you a lot for your efforts! I will try that new one. I hope I'll get through, but now it's definitely clearer to me. Just one more question: Why is it exactly a problem that before this step we only know that $|Y_n-Y|$ is greater than a positive number, which is random? I always thought that this would not matter. Why is it important to have more control here through the $A$?

Comment: I've edited the OP. Is it correct now?

Comment: It seems what you did is correct. Actually, the introduction of $A$ is only in order to use the definition of convergence in probability. It's not really a problem to have something random as if $X_n\to X$ in probability then $YX_n\to YX$ for all $Y$.

Comment: Okay then I understood everything. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this a consequence of the continuous mapping theorem?

Since Y is different to zero almost surely, the function g(x)=1/x satisfies the condition $P[Y\in C^c(g)]=0$, where $C^c(g)$ denotes the set of discontinuity points of $g$ (which in this case equals the set $\{0\}$). Hence we obtain $\frac{1}{Y_n}\to \frac{1}{Y}$ in probability.

Since $X_n\to X$ in probability and $Z_n\to Z$ in probability implies $X_nZ_n\to XZ$ in probability (this is proved in Resnick's "A Probability Path" using subsequences), the result follows taking $Z_n=\frac{1}{Y_n}$ and $Z=\frac{1}{Y}$.